# Yahoo YQL returning INKApi error

Tags: api, yahoo, yql

I am starting to get a little desperate: a few days (maybe a week or two ago) Yahoo API - YQL that was previously working correctly started returning INKApi error.

Specifically, I am talking about Yahoo Fantasy Sports (baseball) API.

I am definitely not the only one receiving the error. But Yahoo is not reacting to posts on their message boards, see:
https://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/Fantasy-Sports-YQL-Console-returning-INKApi/1399927585884-7008ef4d-0696-4114-b789-1840b0f798ff
https://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/Fantasy-Baseball-All-Star-Break/1405604995092-827c4ff0-8517-4814-825b-222345dc1a16

I tried to contact them through their contact form as well, but no reaction at all.

Does anyone have a solution for this? An idea about when (or if) Yahoo will address this issue? A direct contact to someone at Yahoo who could help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more than a month, Yahoo mysteriously woke up and corrected the error. The API is working again (at least for me), so the problem seems to be fixed for now.

However, we should all be aware that their service comes with no guarantee and there is no way to contact them. So all developers should take this into account when trying to work with Yahoo API...

Answer (score 0):

I think contacting them is the only way so that they can modify their api and give you the developers what they wanted ..In my opinion  we dont have anything to do witrh this..You must contact someone at yahoo..

See this link..https://developer.yahoo.com/forum/YQL/Fantasy-Sports-YQL-Console-returning-INKApi/1399927585884-7008ef4d-0696-4114-b789-1840b0f798ff

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 1. If I had a functioning contact, I would contact Yahoo. But they just do not answer to their contact form or to the message boards. I don't have an e-mail. 2. The link you provided was included in my original question. 3. You can see replies from a few people as desperate as me with this problem. The service just isn't working and there seems to be no way to contact Yahoo and make them fix it.